# NonUniqueObjectException and IdentifierGenerationException - cannot update table

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I using MySQL, Hibernate, JPA, and Spring and my problem is that I cannot update child table in association one-to-one; I'm using a foreign strategy.

When i use saveOrUpdate and i call first time method i can save entity to database but when i call it once more(update) i get NonUniqueObjectException. So i change saveorupdate to marge but then i get exception IdentifierGenerationException. I tried many solution but none of them solve my problem.

My Entity User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", uniqueConstraints = {
@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"login"})
})
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
public class User implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "user_id")
private int user_id;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "users")
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
private UserInformation userInformation;

fields,getters,setters...
```

My Entity UserInformation

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_information")
public class UserInformation implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign", 
                  parameters = {@Parameter(name = "property", value = "users")})
@Column(name = "user_information_id", unique = true)
private int user_information_id;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private User users;
fields,getters,setters....
```

method when exception throw

```
@Override
public void updateOrSaveUserInformation(int user_id,
        UserInformation userInformation) throws ObjectNotFoundException {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    User user = (User) session.get(User.class, user_id);
    user.setUserInformation(userInformation);
    userInformation.setUser(user);
    session.merge(user);
}
```

I call  updateOrSaveUserInformation from my controller where i submit form with ModelAttribute UserInformation and i pass UserInformation from form to this method,i keep Userinformation in SessionAttribute.

when i call this method i get exception

```
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one  
property [adrian.example.musicplayer.model.User.UserInformation.users]
```

I dont know where is problem i set user in UserInformation

```
userInformation.setUser(user);
```

when i user saveOrUpdate i get exception

```
org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: A different object with the same identifier 
value was already associated with the session : 
[adrian.example.musicplayer.model.User.UserInformation#26]; nested exception is 
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value  
was 
already associated with the session :   
[adrian.example.musicplayer.model.User.UserInformation#26]
```

number 26 is id if from User.

I also notice when i call updateOrSaveUserInformation in second time i get data From tables UserInformation

```
  user.getUserInformation() //its not null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation for the issues:**

1) When you are getting `User` details using:

```
User user = (User) session.get(User.class, user_id);
```

then Hibernate loads your `UserInformation` object as well. So in memory Hibernate noted that an object of type `UserInformation` with id as `26` is available in memory.

2) Now when you have **only** this line of code:

```
user.setUserInformation(userInformation);
```

and then calling `session.saveOrUpdate(user)` then Hibernate throws an exception as:

```
 org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [.org.package...UserInformation.users]
```

this is because as per your mapping the `Id` for `UserInformation` is mapped with `foreign` key strategy of `User`. So it tries to get the `users` (which is of type `User`) property and tries to find its `Id`, as this `Id` is `null`, Hibernate is not able to assign `Id` to your `UserInformation` object. So that is the reason it says : `attempted to assign id from null property users`.

3) Now to fix the error in step-2, if you try to add one more line of code:

```
userInformation.setUsers(user);
```

and then call the `session.saveOrUpdate(user)`, then hibernate again throws an exception as:

```
 org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [org.package....UserInformation#26]
```

This is because, you are passing a new `UserInformation` object to your custom method, so this object is not having any `Id`. So when you call `saveOrUpdate` , then hibernate tries to pick the `Id` from `users` property which is `26` and then tries to assign it to your new `UserInformation` object.

Finally now you have two `UserInformation` objects with same `Id` as `26` (as per step-1 & step-3). Because of this hibernate throws `NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session`

**Solution:**

To fix these issues you can do this:

```
User user = (User) session.get(User.class, user_id);
UserInformation info = user.getUserInformation();
info.setPropertyName(userInformation.getPropertyName());
session.saveOrUpdate(user);
```

Just get the `UserInformation` object available in `User` and then set all the required properties, then save the `User` object.